# SQL Input Sanitization Library

Tags: c#, .net, sql, vb.net

I'm working with a third-party API that requires me to give it complete, runnable SQL query text - I cannot use approaches such as parameterization in order to guard against input that may break a SQL statement, or worse, allow for SQL injection.

As a result, I'm looking for a library (preferably for .NET) that will help me to sanitize inputs as I am building up a query (e.g. in its most basic sense, escaping special characters in a string, ensuring table names are legal, etc.).

I know I can using regular find/replace style of replacing unacceptable characters with the corresponding escape code, but as [this article](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) describes, it's very possible to overlook a particular edge case. I also didn't want to re-invent the wheel if it already existed.

The closest thing I've found so far to what I'm looking for is Microsoft's [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.Parser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.aspx) namespace, which contains an EscapeSequence class that can help prepare valid query statement tokens. (E.g. it will turn `O'Reilly` into `'O''Reilly'`)

However, I was hoping to find something a bit more stand-alone (i.e. doesn't require installation of SQL Server-related components).

Has anyone encountered such a library?